# Some doubts about Xamarin and Net 5

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-5

I would like to create a new Xamarin project, I choose the option Xamarin.Android, because I would like to develop the most closer to native application. in this case, in the property of the project, as target I can choose the android version.

If I choose Xamarin.Forms as project, I can choose some version of net standard, but I can't choose Net 5. Although I can create another Net 5 projects, like libraries.

So I would like to if it is possible to create Net 5 Xamarin projects or not.

It seems logic that if I want to develop a native android application, Net 5 is not an option, instead i have to choose the android version, but I wanted to be sure if I am right or I am doing something wrong.

And finally, if I create a Net 5 library, could I use it in a Xamarin.Android project? I ask this because I have create a solution with two projects, one is a Xamarin.Android and the other is a class library in Net 5. I have added the reference of the Net 5 to the Xamarin.Android project. When I try to compile, I get the error that MonoAndroid version 8.1 is not compatible with a library in Net 5.

Thanks.

Comment: This was covered in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/ You will have to wait till .Net 6 (And Xamarin.Forms is migrating to .NET MAUI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in your finding.

Xamarin is expected to work with .NET 6 in November 2021. Though even that comes with some caveats like that Xamarin for watchOS won't transition in that time frame.

Some info: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/09/29/xamarin-forms-5-preview.aspx

Comment: Looks like the .NET MAUI schedule has slipped to Q2 2022 :( https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/update-on-dotnet-maui/#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20.NET%20MAUI%20will%20not%20be%20ready%20for%20production%20with%20.NET%206%20GA%20in%20November.%20We%20want%20to%20provide%20the%20best%20experience%2C%20performance%2C%20and%20quality%20on%20day%201%20to%20our%20users%20and%20to%20do%20that%2C%20we%20need%20to%20slip%20the%20schedule.%20We%20are%20now%20targeting%20early%20Q2%20of%202022%20for%20.NET%20MAUI%20GA.

Comment: Actually MAUI is just a wrapper around those technologies so it has nothing to do with .NET 6 - but it is likely that Xamarin.Forms will still target .NET Standard. But you will be able to use .NET 6 in the native projects and thus indirectly in Xamarin.Forms too.